# Update Texlive with wget or rsync

Tags: texlive, texlive-2019

I want to download last version of TexLive by wget or rsync in win 10.

I don't know best way for this purpose.

I find this command line for wget but it does not work:

> wget -N --continue --no-dns-cache --no-host-directories --cut-dirs=3
>   --mirror --no-parent --recursive --timestamping "ftp://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/" pause

What is best way for download and update texlive?

Thanks alot.

Comment: You need to download the installation programme and run that.

Comment: See https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html.

Comment: @cfr, I download wget and rsync and run .bat file contain above commad, but not work for me.

Comment: Did you run `install-tl-windows.bat` from an administrative command-prompt? If it is trying to use `wget`, something has already gone wrong.